# Apostrophe CMS: Is it possible to customize the UI on apostrophe-pages?

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I need to add a column on the 'Pages' modal in the Apostrophe CMS and potentially override the existing column titles (i.e. "Link" to something a little more intuitive). The closest thing I saw in the online documentation was here: https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/reference/modules/apostrophe-pages#contextmenu

Though, when I paste the example code into my apostrophe-pages/index.js, I don't see any change anywhere in the CMS.

Hope someone can offer any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contextMenu` is the menu revealed by the button in the bottom left. It's named that because it (generally) reflects the context in which it's being used (e.g., "new-page" creates a new page as a child of the page you're on).

[image: screenshot of the context menu from the demo site]

Generally for pieces you would want to look at [the "Adding columns" documentation](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/advanced-topics/advanced-pieces-topics/adding-columns). However pages are special, so have [their own "reorganize" view](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/reorganize.html) and [accompanying JS](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/public/js/reorganize.js) to control the page tree structure.

Comment: As far as setting req.contextMenu to override the default settings, what file would this code go in? It's not very clear in the documentation and I get errors when I place it in app.js

Comment: It would be on a request for an `apostrophe-pages` document. Possibly `self.serve`, or similar ones like `self.pageServe` for custom pages and `self.showPage` and `self.indexPage` for pieces pages. I'm not 100% on that. I've only seen it used in `showPage`.